# How to find the extremals of the functional?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, mathematical-optimization, variational-calculus

How to find the extremals of the functional by Wolfram *Mathematica*?

$$J(y(x))=\int_{0}^{1}\big(y(x)^3+y'(x)\big)dx$$

Comment: Did you try to solve the corresponding Euler-Lagrange equations? What are the boundary conditions at x_0 and x_1?

Comment: y(x_0)=1 and y(x_1)=2. I am very new in Mathematica. How to find Euler-Lagrange eqs. by Mathematica?

Comment: And can Mathematica give step by step solution for this problem? (like in the differential equations)

Comment: You need to load VariationalMethods with `Needs["VariationalMethods``"]`  (sorry, I do not know how to display a single apostrophe) and can use VariationalD then. The boundary conditions can be implemented by the Lagrange multiplier method.

Comment: Let me also note that your functional is unbounded, therefore the usual variational methods do not yield anything useful.

Comment: If integral from 0 to 1?

Comment: marmor, wrap the code containing backtick with double backtiks. Like: \`\`whatever` \`\`

Comment: Thanks! @Kuba. @HD239 : consider `y[x_] = 1 + x + \[Alpha] x (x - 1);`. This function satisfies your boundary conditions. However, the integral J can be an arbitrarily large negative or positive number. This shows that there is no extremum.

Comment: Firstly, thank you very much. I got it. There is no extremum in the example. Could you help me to write Mathematica code in order to find extremals of a functional like my example?

Comment: Of course I could but I believe the help in ``Needs["VariationalMethods`"]`` is better than what I could come up with. Just look at the examples in `EulerEquations` and the corresponding documentation.